# C# - XML doc not being saved into the database

Tags: c#, sql, xml, types, breeze

I have this code that is converting JSON to XML and then inserting the data into a table. But the table column where the xml data goes is null. It is not inserting.

```
[HttpPost]
        public void SaveData(Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject data)
        {
            string agency = data.Root.ToString();
            XmlDocument doc = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(agency, "agency");

            Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken[] ArrAgency = data.Root.ToArray();

            dynamic DeserializedData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(data.ToString());

            tblAgencyQuery tblAgencyQuery = new tblAgencyQuery();
            tblAgencyQuery.QueryID = Guid.NewGuid();
            tblAgencyQuery.QueryText = doc;
            tblAgencyQuery.AgencyID = DeserializedData.agencyID;
            tblAgencyQuery.CreatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;

            _ContextProvider.Context.tblAgencyQuery.Add(tblAgencyQuery);
            _ContextProvider.Context.Entry(tblAgencyQuery).State = System.Data.EntityState.Added;
            _ContextProvider.Context.SaveChanges();

        }
```

**My model**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace AgencyUpdate.Models
{
    public class tblAgencyQuery
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid QueryID { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public System.Xml.XmlDocument QueryText { get; set; }
        public int AgencyID { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**SQL script for table**

```
USE [GenesisOnline]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[tblAgencyQuery]    Script Date: 20/09/2013 11:17:34 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblAgencyQuery](
        [QueryID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
        [QueryText] [xml] NULL,
        [AgencyID] [int] NULL,
        [CreatedDate] [datetime] NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_tblAgencyQuery] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [QueryID] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON

, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblAgencyQuery] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_tblAgencyQuery_CreatedDate]  DEFAULT (getutcdate()) FOR [CreatedDate]
GO
```

Any idea why this is not inserting the xml?

Comment: Is it really meant to have the `[NotMapped]` attribute?

Comment: @RowlandShaw Without that attribute I get a runtime error. I am using Breeze.WebApi to do my CRUD methods.

Comment: [NotMapped] means " ignore this when mapping to/from database.
See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.notmappedattribute.aspx
 So that's why nothing is being inserted. What is the runtime error?

Comment: You probably want to fix that runtime error (whatever it is) as you're currently saying that the XML is not persisted to the database.

Answer (score 2):

Certain ORMs don't support data types which contain very large values (e.g. text data type, etc.).  While I'm not familiar with Breeze, I wouldn't be surprised to find out that was the cause of your underlying runtime error.  I believe the max size for the xml data type is several GB.

As other have said, [NotMapped] is what is causing the null.  You're explicitly telling the system not to do anything with that field.

You need to address the (probable) underlying issue with your data type to eliminate the runtime error and then remove the [NotMapped] attribute.  Since I'm not familiar with Breeze I can't give you specific guidance, but this should at least be a starting point to base a search on.

Comment: Thanks I will look into this more.